# Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array when using Do Until Loop

Tags: arrays, vb.net

```
Private Sub TxtCoin_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtCoin.TextChanged
    ' declare a six row six column array for coin value ranges
    Static dblCoins(,) As Double = {{"0", "10"},
        {"10.01", "50"},
        {"50.01", "100"},
        {"100.01", "500"},
        {"500.01", "5000"},
        {"5000.01", "1000000000
        "}}
    ' declare parellel array
    Static strMsgVal() As String =
        {"Cheap", "Average", "Above Average", "Valuable", "Very Valuable", "Extremely Valuabele"}

    ' display the coin value message
    Dim strMessage As String
    Dim dblCoinVal = dblCoins
    Dim strMessa = strMsgVal.ToString

    strMessage = TxtCoin.Text

    ' search dblCoins for the amount 
    ' continue searching until the end of
    ' the array or the amount is found

    Do Until dblCoinVal = dblCoins.Length OrElse
            strMessage = dblCoins(dblCoinVal)
        dblCoinVal += 1
    Loop


    If strMessa = dblCoinVal.ToString Then
        lblCoinDescriptions.Text = strMessa.ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an integer")
    End If
```

Trying to get my label to display a message when the user enters a certain value in the text box range in my array and am getting an error.

Visual basic

Comment: Yes I need to retap it. Ty

Comment: Made a mistake apparently

Comment: Fixed the tag ty will remember now

Comment: To begin, turn Option Strict on. You declare an array of Double and then dump strings into it.

Comment: What is the expected value of strMessa after this line of code?  Dim strMessa = strMsgVal.ToString

Comment: StrMessa should hold the values that are in strMsgVal array. I had option strict on but then most of my code was giving an error with it.

Comment: k fixed option strict is on and "" are taken out of the array. I just need to figure out the double conversion to string. Ty

Comment: ToString called on an array will give you the Type. The value of strMessa is System.String[] You need to reference the individual elements of the array to get the values.

Comment: What is the expected value of dblCoins.Length?

Comment: DblCoins should be the array values. I need to show the array message of cheap etc when my double array 10-10000000 equals 10.01-50 I need to display cheap and so on.

Comment: yes, but what is the expected value of dblCoins.Length? What you are comparing to in your Do Until loop.

Comment: Since you now have Option Strict on, do you show red squigglies in that same Do loop?

Comment: I made it to equal the dblCoins array values to try and loop through it. Till it gets to a certain value then displays the message.

Comment: I need it to show the message when the user enters a number in a text box

Comment: I am not trying to be mean; just asking questions to make you think about what your code is doing. The first statement in your do loop is trying to compare a 2 dimensional array of type double to a single Integer. Can't be done. I think you need to study up on arrays and how to access their elements. You did fine declaring them, although, I don't quite see why you made them static. See if you can get rid of the red squiggles and then come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: Ok tyvm for your help this is my first Vb array. My teacher wants me to code a two dimensional then a parallel very confusing to me.

Comment: I have used 2 dimensional arrays and i have used parallel arrays but never together. It would be like an Excel spreadsheet on top of another spreadsheet where cell 0,0 would relate to cell 0,0 on the second spreadsheet. Not a project for a beginner in arrays. Are you sure you have the details of the project correct?

Comment: Create a two-dimensional array with minimum and maximum ranges of dollar values for determining how valuable a coin is.  Then, create a parallel string array that stores string values for the descriptions for these ranges:
$0 - $10 - Cheap
$10.01 - $50 - Average
$50.01 - $100 - Above Average
$100.01 - $500 - Valuable
$500.01 - $5000 - Very Valuable
$5000.01 and up - Extremely Valuable
In the "New Coin" form, when the user enters the coin's value, display the description for its value by checking the entered value against the value ranges.   description from the parallel

Comment: That's my assignment very hard and not easy for me to understand. One array would have been allot easier.

Comment: Maybe this will help a little. I looped through the indexes of the two arrays and printed the results in the Immediate window. The results were  -Index (0,0) = 0
-Index (0,1) = 10
-Index (1,0) = 10.01
-Index (1,1) = 50
-Index (2,0) = 50.01
-Index (2,1) = 100
-Index (3,0) = 100.01
-Index (3,1) = 500
-Index (4,0) = 500.01
-Index (4,1) = 5000
-Index (5,0) = 5000.01
-Index (5,1) = 1000000000
-Index (0) = Cheap 
-Index (1) = Average 
-Index (2) = Above Average 
-Index (3) = Valuable 
-Index (4) = Very Valuable 
-Index (5) = Extremely Valuable

Comment: I’ve been thinking I need to define the index’s but how exactly I’m going to get all of it with the results will be tricky. Seems like an advanced assignment for an intro class. Ty it does help.

Comment: I have done a bit more research and it seems that a one dimensional array cannot be a parallel array to a two dimensional array so don't feel bad. What you are asked to do doesn't exist in the strictest sense.

Comment: Wow I guess I’ll just declare a parallel and see if it’s good enough. Trying my best but it’s difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the code in the TextedChanged event because it will run every time the users enters a single digit.

```
Private Sub butOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butOK.Click
        Dim dblCoins(,) As Double = {{0, 10},
        {10.0, 50},
        {50.0, 100},
        {100.0, 500},
        {500.0, 5000},
        {5000.0, 1000000000}}
        Dim strMsgVal() As String =
       {"Cheap", "Average", "Above Average", "Valuable", "Very Valuable", "Extremely Valuabele"}
        Dim x As Double
        If Double.TryParse(txtCoin.Text, x) Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To 5
                If x > dblCoins(i, 0) And x <= dblCoins(i, 1) Then
                    MessageBox.Show($"The value of {x:c} has the Apprasal Value of {strMsgVal(i)}")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot evaluate a negative number or 0.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between 0 and 1000000000 without any commas or dollar signs.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

I think this code forces the arrays to be parallel. Please mark as answered if this helps you.

Comment: Tyvm this does help. I appreciate it very much.